# Align equals signs between unboxed and boxed amsmath split lines

Tags: boxes, alignment

I'm trying to figure out how to align the equals sign with the rest of the equals on the last line. Unfortunately, I get the offset alignment you can see in the image below. Any recommendations on how to get things aligned around the `&=` for the final line?

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\boxed}[2][\fboxsep]{{
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{#1}\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.8}\fbox{\m@th$\displaystyle#2$}}}
\makeatother

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        26(x-14)-23(x-14)&=39\\
        26x-364-23x+322&=39\\
        3x-42&=39\\
        3x&=81\\
        \\
        \boxed[10]{\mathbf{\therefore x&=27}}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,bm,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   26(x-14)-23(x-14)&=39\\
   26x-364-23x+322&=39\\
   3x-42&=39\\
   3x&=81\\[2mm]
   \Aboxed{\bm{\therefore x}&\bm{=27}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't enclose the `&` symbol in braces (from `mathbf{...}`) (and again in `\boxed{...}`).

I suggest a different approach using `align*` from `mathtools` and `tikzmark`:

[image]

Note: use `\bm` instead of `\mathbf` to get the bold math style.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
        26(x-14)-23(x-14)&=39\\
        26x-364-23x+322&=39\\
        3x-42&=39\\
        3x&=81\\[2ex]
        \tikzmark{a}\bm{\therefore x}&\bm{=27}
\end{align*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[red,thick]([shift={(-2mm,-3mm)}]pic cs:a) rectangle ++ (2.0,.8);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```